installing Cachet status web page on a managed server by an ISP
Good day all
My Problem:
I've recently started as a junior developer at a company looking to deploy Cachet's open source status page system on to a managed server which is hosted by a service provider. The installation keeps failing at the last step. Please see the attached image.
Error Message:
    pieafuhwdd@www28:~/public_html/status/cachet$ /usr/bin/php7.1 artisan cachet:install
    
     Do you want to configure Cachet before installing? (yes/no) [no]:
     > no
    
    Installing Cachet...
    Clearing settings cache...
    Settings cache cleared!
    System was installed!
    **************************************
    *     Application In Production!     *
    **************************************
    
     Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
     > yes
    
    Application key set successfully.
    Configuration cache cleared!
    Configuration cached successfully!
    Route cache cleared!
    Routes cached successfully!
    Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views] To [/resources/views/errors]
    Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views] To [/resources/views/vendor/notifications]
    Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views] To [/resources/views/vendor/pagination]
    Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views] To [/resources/views/vendor/mail]
    Publishing complete.
    
    In Connection.php line 664:
    
      could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cachet_
      db and table_name = migrations)
    
    
    In PDOConnection.php line 31:
    
      could not find driver


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  could not find driver

What I expected to happen:
This being the final step in Cachets installation guide, I expected the web page to be deployed and accessible via the url.
Either I am missing a certain driver or the user for the database does not have the correct permissions in place.
I have 2 questions:
Am I right in thinking its a missing driver or limit of database permissions?
Or
Is it even possible to install Cachet onto a managed server where I am not the root user?
I am very new to all this. Any advice will really be appreciated.

Please don't post images of code or errors!

"Either I am missing a certain driver or the user for the database ..." What does the error message say?

I've removed the image and replaced it with the error code

Is this problem really related to Composer? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?
